# Body background does'nt fill full page

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying use html background and body background as different. when i use body color it does not cover whole page for index page. however it is working for other pages!
here is my code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to NY All STAR's offical website</title>
    <meta name ="Description" content="NYAS">
    <meta name="Description" content = "A_New_York_based_cricket_club">
    <meta name="tag" content ="NYPCL,nyas">
    <meta name ="tag" content="cricket">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">


</head>

    <body>

    <header>
    <img src="images/logo.png" width=1200 height=300 alt="All star">
    </header>
    <br>
     <nav class="navv">
        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li id="current" class="nav-item"><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
         </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">PLAYERS</a>
                <ul class="nav-submenu">
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="abir.html">Abir Khan</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="afzal.html">Afzal Hossain</a>    </li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="polash.html">Ashfaqur Rahman</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="ashraf.html">Ashrafur Rahman</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="azad.html">Azad Ahmed</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="jibran.html">Jibran Khan</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="junayed.html">Junayed Ahmed</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="korban.html">Korban Ali</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="shaikot.html">MD. Shaikot Alom</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="tanmoy.html">MD Tanmoy Hossain</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="suleman.html">Mohammed Suleman</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="monju.html">Monirul Haque</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="monju.html">Monjur Hussain</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="maju.html">Muazam Hussain</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="mustafizur.html">Mustafizur Rahman</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="pervej.html">Pervej Rahman</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="prashant.html">Prashant Nair</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="shuvo.html">Rakib Shuvo</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="sami.html">Sami Chowdhury</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="sanjil.html">Sanjil Chowdhury</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="saqif.html">Saqif Haider</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>     
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="schedule.html">SCHEDULE</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="result.html">RESULT</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="stats.html">STATS</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">MEDIA</a>
            <ul class="nav-submenu">
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="?=submenu-1">PHOTO</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="?=submenu-2">VIDEO</a></li>
            </ul>     
         </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="links.html">LINKS</a>
         </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">LIVE STREAM</a>
            <ul class="nav-submenu">
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="livecricket.html">LIVE CRICKET</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="banglaradio.html">LIVE RADIO</a></li>
            </ul>     
         </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav-list">
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
```

```
<aside >
    <div class="widget" >
    <p><script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USNY0996?template=GENXH&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget"></script></p>
    </div>
</aside>

            <!--Beginning of photo Slideshow -->
    <div class ="left"> <!--bordered slideshow here-->

    <ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/slideshow/img_1.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">
    <h2>T-20 Champion 2013</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/slideshow/img_2.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/slideshow/img_3.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/slideshow/img_4.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
    <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/slideshow/img_5.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
    <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/slideshow/img_6.JPG" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
    <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1">
    </label>
    <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2">

    </label>
    <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3">
    </label>
    <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4">
    </label>
    <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5">
    </label>
    <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6">
    </label>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <!--End of Photo Slideshow -->  

    <br>
<section >
    <div class="welcome">
    <h3>Welcome to NYAS</h3>
    <p>
        <em>NY All STAR</em> is a cricket club which is made up of young                      cricketers 
        who are highly determined and focused in their game. This club 
        joined BCANA League in 2011. 
    </p>
    <p> In 2013, NY All STAR Participated in NYPCL and won the t20 first    division league. They also became the League <b>Runners-up</b> of Division A.
    </p>
    </div>
</section>

<br>
<footer>
 <!-- footer -->

<div id="f" class="clearfix">
  <div class="col">
    <ul class="btm-left">
      <li><img src="images/logo.png" height="150" width="160"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div class="col">

        <ul class="btm-center">
          <li><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnyascc&amp;width=450&amp;height=395&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=false&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:395px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="col">

    <ul class="btm-right">
      <li><b>Links</b></li>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
      <li><a href="schedule.html">SCHEDULE</a></li>
      <li><a href="result.html">RESULT</a></li>
      <li><a href="stats.html">STATS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PLAYERS</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.html">LINKS</a></li>
      <li><a href="livecricket.html">LIVE CRICKET</a></li>
      <li><a href="banglaradio.html">LIVE RADIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>
<!-- @end footer -->

     </body>

     </html>
```

Css code is here:

```
body {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border: 2px solid black;
background: #F0F0F0;
background-size: cover;
    font-size: 87.5%;
width: 1200px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin: 15px auto;
padding: 15px 25px;
display: block;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Please give me a solution why is it happening.

here is a link you can look into: http://cst2309.hostei.com/

Thank you

Comment: could you able to send fiddle link ??

Comment: Its a tedious job to replicate your issue. At-least try and reflect that as a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [**Bin**](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: here is the link for my project: http://cst2309.hostei.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have given margin 15px to the body. Don't give any margin or padding to the body. instead give padding and margin to the elements inside it.

Comment: if i dont use margin, then body doesnt stay in the middle of the screen.i tried with out margin but nothing good

Comment: try this... create a div just after the body, include everything in it , to this div apply this css margin:0 auto; this should work. and also remove the body width and give it to this div. and also give background-color to this div not the body.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have closing  tag. This can be the case as browsers try to find omitting tag for every main tag. Try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to NY All STAR's offical website</title>
<meta name ="Description" content="NYAS">
<meta name="Description" content = "A_New_York_based_cricket_club">
<meta name="tag" content ="NYPCL,nyas">
<meta name ="tag" content="cricket">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">


</head>

<body>

<header>
<img src="images/logo.png" width=1200 height=300 alt="All star">
</header>
<br>
<nav class="navv">
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li id="current" class="nav-item"><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">PLAYERS</a>
        <ul class="nav-submenu">
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="abir.html">Abir Khan</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="afzal.html">Afzal Hossain</a>    </li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="polash.html">Ashfaqur Rahman</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="ashraf.html">Ashrafur Rahman</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="azad.html">Azad Ahmed</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="jibran.html">Jibran Khan</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="junayed.html">Junayed Ahmed</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="korban.html">Korban Ali</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="shaikot.html">MD. Shaikot Alom</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="tanmoy.html">MD Tanmoy Hossain</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="suleman.html">Mohammed Suleman</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="monju.html">Monirul Haque</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="monju.html">Monjur Hussain</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="maju.html">Muazam Hussain</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="mustafizur.html">Mustafizur Rahman</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="pervej.html">Pervej Rahman</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="prashant.html">Prashant Nair</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="shuvo.html">Rakib Shuvo</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="sami.html">Sami Chowdhury</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="sanjil.html">Sanjil Chowdhury</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="saqif.html">Saqif Haider</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="schedule.html">SCHEDULE</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="result.html">RESULT</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="stats.html">STATS</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">MEDIA</a>
        <ul class="nav-submenu">
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="?=submenu-1">PHOTO</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="?=submenu-2">VIDEO</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="links.html">LINKS</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">LIVE STREAM</a>
        <ul class="nav-submenu">
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="livecricket.html">LIVE CRICKET</a></li>
            <li class="nav-submenu-item"><a href="banglaradio.html">LIVE RADIO</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<aside >
    <div class="widget" >
        <p><script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USNY0996?template=GENXH&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget"></script></p>
    </div>
</aside>

<!--Beginning of photo Slideshow -->
<div class ="left"> <!--bordered slideshow here-->

    <ul class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/img_1.jpg" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>T-20 Champion 2013</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/img_2.JPG" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/img_3.JPG" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/img_4.JPG" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/img_5.JPG" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/img_6.JPG" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-dots">
            <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1">
            </label>
            <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2">

            </label>
            <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3">
            </label>
            <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4">
            </label>
            <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5">
            </label>
            <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6">
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!--End of Photo Slideshow -->

<br>
<section >
    <div class="welcome">
        <h3>Welcome to NYAS</h3>
        <p>
            <em>NY All STAR</em> is a cricket club which is made up of young                      cricketers
            who are highly determined and focused in their game. This club
            joined BCANA League in 2011.
        </p>
        <p> In 2013, NY All STAR Participated in NYPCL and won the t20 first    division league. They also became the League <b>Runners-up</b> of Division A.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>

<br>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i edited mypost little bit. problem starts when i add footer with the page. please look at this link http://cst2309.hostei.com